# What is the default upper limit of Select statement in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL workbench, `SELECT` statements have a 1000-result limit by default. Will that still be the case if I run a similar query from PHP? Does MySQL have a maximum number of rows that a `SELECT` statement can retrieve and, if so, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no upper limit.

In fact, you can just leave `limit` out of the query and return all the results, if you want.